# Unable to find number for twilio

Tags: twilio

I have created a twilio account. Just got into a confusion. The account is in test mode, in that case if I need to send an actual message to a phone number, do I need to use live credentials or test credentials?

I tried with test credentials and magic number there is no error but no actual message is delivered to the number. I am using +1 as well.

can anyone suggest me how to deliver a message using test mode, do I need to buy a number. Although the purchased number is not delivering message using the twilio watermark as it used to do.

please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To send real messages that arrive at a phone with a trial account, you need to use the live credentials and the trial phone number you get with the account.

Test credentials are only used to test that your calls to specific APIs are correct without actually buying numbers or sending messages.

One more important thing, you need to [verify your number with Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio) as in trial mode you can only send messages to and make calls to numbers that are verified.